# How can I dismiss a kivy popup from a button class created in Python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Here is the python code:

```
class Button3(ToggleButton):
   def on_press(self):
       self.background_color = (0,1,0,1)
       SecondWindow().selected_item(self)

   def on_release(self):
       self.background_color = (0,0.2,0.5,0.5)
       LightsPop().dismiss()
class LightsPop(Popup):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LightsPop, self).__init__(**kwargs)


def on_open(self):
    with open('popupid/light_selected', 'w') as light:
        light.write("")
        light.close()

        for x in fixture_list.split("\n"):
            b= Button3(text=x,font_size=14,size_hint=(0.9,None),height=40,group='lights',back_color=(0.5,0.5,0.5,0),background_color=(0,0.2,0.5,0.5),background_normal='')

        self.ids.drop2.add_widget(b)
```

And the Kv:

```
<LightsPop>:
    size_hint:(0.8,0.8)
    title:"Fixture List"
    id: drop_lights
    auto_dismiss:True
    on_dismiss: app.root.get_screen('second').updatetext()
    BoxLayout:
        spacing:2
        padding:2
        id: drop_lightsbox
        orientation:"vertical"
        ScrollView:
            id: scroll_lights
            BoxLayout:
                id:drop2
                orientation:"vertical"
                size_hint:(1,5)
        BoxLayout:

            size_hint: (1,0.14)
            spacing:3
            padding:3
            orientation:"horizontal"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint:(1,4.5)

            Button:
                id: close_light
                size_hint: (0.5,1)

                text: "close"
                on_release:drop_lights.dismiss()
```

The problem is at `Button3(TogggleButton)` on_release in py code (I tried with self.parents, I made a method in popup window class which executes `self.dismiss()` and I called that method from button with `LightsPop().func()`, but it didn't work.

Comment: calling `LightsPop().func()` creates a new instance of `LightsPop` and calls its `func()` method. That new instance of `LightsPop` is not the one that is displayed. You need to access the actual instance that is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved i added b.bind(on_release = self.dismiss)

```
class LightsPop(Popup):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LightsPop, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def on_open(self):
        with open('popupid/light_selected', 'w') as light:
            light.write("")
            light.close()

        for x in fixture_list.split("\n"):
            b= Button3(text=x,font_size=14,size_hint=(0.9,None),height=40,group='lights',back_color=(0.5,0.5,0.5,0),background_color=(0,0.2,0.5,0.5),background_normal='')
            b.bind(on_release = self.dismiss)
            self.ids.drop2.add_widget(b)
```